# Need a script or software to modify a lot of html files at once

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, replace

I have about 3400 files in a tree structure (about 80% are html files).

1. I need to modify every html file to remove

   style and old things like font attribute and add another style.
2. I need to change the root of all links that are in the html. e.g. change /old/path/ to /new/path at the href attribute.
3. I need to remove some links. e.g. links that points to google.com need to be removed, so `<a href="http://www.google.com">as google said</a>` should be only "as google said".

Is there any software that can do this for me?
Is it possible to make a script?

I have no knowledge about scripting for this to work, I thing this could be the fast way... anybody wants to help me?

Thanks !

Comment: I'd recommend Python and BeautifulSoup for this task, but you'd need *some* programming nouse.

Comment: There is no *fast* way to do this, sadly. I'd also suggest Python and BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up a script that opens a just single HTML file, parses it with a reliable HTML parser (BeautifulSoup comes to mind as a great example) and then traverses it in one of two ways: in the SAX model, writing functions representing the targets for your rewriting rules or in the DOM model, writing your rules as XPath queries and performing actions on matching DOM nodes.

Then just run the script on all your HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup!
2. pick a scripting language
3. find out how to give a recursive file listing
4. learn how to read the contents of files and save files
5. open all files and apply a function to the contents of each file
6. the function should be the list of the multiple steps you just described and should have the new data as its return value
7. save the data back to the file

usually search and replace is easy in most languages. if you need it to where you have conditional parsing you may need an xml/html parser or may need to learn regular expressions. It's always better to make sure it works for 1 file first ;).